# Minecraft seeds for a high landscape?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Which Minecraft seeds can generate a massive high-altitude landscape?

Comment: What does "massive high-altitude landscape" even mean?

Comment: This sounds suspiciously like a game/shopping recommendation.

Comment: @MarkTrapp I knew there was something fishy about this question but I couldn't put my finger on it.  I think you're right.

Comment: It's not a *great* question, but I have no idea how you interpreted it as a "game/shopping recommendation" question, @Mark :) It certainly isn't spam, and it's fairly clear (to me) what he wants - just hard to answer. A better question might be - "where can I find a list of Minecraft seeds and what they generated?"

Comment: He wants a seed with a starting position where the Y-value is right near/underneath the cloud level, is my take on the question. This would seemingly create an almost solid landmass underneath with only a few pits scattered around. While I'm sure it exists, I don't know how to find it, sorry.

Comment: The effects of seeds change with each version, also.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I don't know if there is a list broken up into categories like what you are asking for, but there is a blog which posts seeds and screenshots of what they generate.

http://www.minecraftseeds.info/